# When logging a user out of a website, on the logout page is it nescecary to start the session before destroying it?

Tags: php, security, authentication

In logout.php is all that is needed

```
session_destroy();
```

or should it be

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

I'm concerned that if a user directly navigates to this page there may be an error destroying the session if one hadn't already been created. On the other hand would the `session_destroy()` destroy the session created in the line above?

Comment: You should also regenerate the session ID when logging the user out.

Comment: @bažmegakapa are you sure this happens when logging out? The first user contributed note says to call `session_regenerate_id(true)` after logging in. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: You should always regenerate the session ID when the user's permissions change (logging in or out are good examples).

Comment: @bažmegakapa why is it necessary to do it both times? I'm not entirely clear why it's necessary at all, is it so the next person to log in doesn't get the same session and end up in another user's account?

Comment: I might have been wrong, on logout you do not certainly need it if the session data is destroyed anyways. Some info: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet#Renew_the_Session_ID_After_Any_Privilege_Level_Change

Comment: @bažmegakapa I think it's better to do both. From link "A complementary recommendation is to use a different session ID or token name (or set of session IDs) **pre and post authentication**, so that the web application can keep track of anonymous users and authenticated users without the risk of exposing or binding the user session between both states."

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call session_start() first... session_destroy() will remove a session completely on the server and therefore calling session_start() beforehand may cause extra processing to create a session to only destroy it one line later.

I would advise viewing further details on the [man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) regarding clearing any associated cookies / session superglobals

Comment: The docs are a little unclear on the matter; my best guess is that `$_SESSION = array();` is not needed if you have not called `session_start()`, but it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Without it I get the error "Trying to destroy uninitialized session"